# Active Admin generates a CSV with column headers only (no other rows) when viewing any page after the first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, activeadmin, kaminari

I'm using Active Admin on the back-end.

I have several pages of records. Everything works fine when I use the built-in functionality to generate a CSV file from the first page of records, but when I try to run the export from Page 2 and above - it generates a blank document with headers only and no data.

Has anyone ever run into this bug? Fix?

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour on activeadmin 0.5.0. Which version are you using? Maybe you want to submit an issue here: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/ (you havea to signup for github though)

Comment: I'm using activeadmin version 0.5.0 on several of my applications and it's an application-wide issue. I did raise this up on their github page: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/1924

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just opened a PR to fix this by making CSV export always respect the current page you're on: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/pull/2419

Ideally we'd like to have an "export every record to one file" functionality, but for now at least the current CSV export link will behave as expected.